# INSERT into temporary table with Identity column from stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, sql-insert, temp-tables

I have this temporary table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpAbsences
(
    idCol   int IDENTITY (1,1)
    , ClientID  int
    , FROMDate  datetime
    , ToDate    datetime
    , NoOfDays  int
    , NoQualDaysForSSP  int
    , AveWeeklyEarnings_Override    float
    , AveWeeklyEarnings_Paid    float
    , QualifyingDaysInWeek  smallint
    , ActualQualifyingDays  smallint
    , Weeks decimal
    , TotalWeeksINTmpAbsence    decimal
    , Linked    int
    , DateCreated   datetime
    , SSPDays   int
    , Location  varchar
    , SSPPaid   float
    )

SET IDENTITY_INSERT #tmpAbsences ON

INSERT #tmpAbsences 
    EXEC sprc_EXPORT_SSP1_LoadtmpAbsencesTable @ClientId
```

and the below stored procedure definition to populate the temp table:

```
CREATE PROC sprc_EXPORT_SSP1_LoadtmpAbsencesTable   
    @ClientId int   
AS
BEGIN
    --DECLARE @ClientID int=9814
    SELECT
        IDENTITY(INT) AS idCol, 
        @ClientID AS ClientID
        --, AB.AbsenceID
        , AB.FROMDate
        , AB.ToDate
        , AB.NoOfDays
        , AB.NoQualDaysForSSP
        , AB.AveWeeklyEarnings_Override
        , AB.AveWeeklyEarnings_Paid
        , SSP.QualifyingDaysInWeek
        , SSP.ActualQualifyingDays
        , CAST(CAST(SSP.ActualQualifyingDays AS DECIMAL(10,2))/CAST(SSP.QualifyingDaysInWeek AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS Weeks
        , SUM(CAST(CAST(SSP.ActualQualifyingDays AS DECIMAL(10,2))/CAST(SSP.QualifyingDaysInWeek AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS DECIMAL(10,2))) OVER(ORDER BY FROMDate ASC) AS TotalWeeksINTmpAbsence
        , (CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(AB2.ClientId) FROM t_Absence AS AB2 WITH (NOLOCK)  
                    LEFT JOIN t_AbsenceCategory AS ABR2 WITH (NOLOCK)  ON (AB2.AbsenceCategoryID = ABR2.AbsenceCategoryID)  AND DATEDIFF(DAY, AB2.ToDate, AB.FROMDate) - 1 >= 0 -- Precedes this absence
                    WHERE AB2.ClientId = @ClientID      
                    AND (DATEDIFF(DAY, AB2.ToDate, AB.FROMDate) - 1 <= 8 * 7) -- but not by more that 8 weeks           
                    AND ABR2.IsSSP > 0 AND ABR.IsSSP > 0
                    AND (DATEDIFF(DAY, AB2.FROMDate, AB2.ToDate) >= 3  
                        or ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, AB2.ToDate, AB.FROMDate)) - ISNULL(dbo.fn_GetTotalNonWorkingDays(@ClientID,AB2.ToDate, AB.FROMDate),0) = 1)
                    ) > 0 
                    AND dbo.fn_IsPIW(AB.AbsenceID, 4) = 1 -- this will take care of checking for continous days AND qualifying days
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Linked'
        , AB.DateCreated
        , SSPDays
        , (SELECT Descn FROM t_Locations WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE LocationId = dbo.fn_CheckClientHistory(@ClientID,14,AB.FROMDate)) AS 'Location' 
        , ISNULL((SELECT SUM(SSPPaid) FROM t_PayrollSSPEmployeePaid AS EP WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE EP.AbsenceID = AB.AbsenceID),0)  AS 'SSPPaid'         
    FROM 
        t_Absence AS AB WITH (NOLOCK) 
    LEFT JOIN 
        t_AbsenceCategory AS ABR WITH (NOLOCK) ON (AB.AbsenceCategoryID = ABR.AbsenceCategoryID)
    INNER JOIN 
        t_PayrollSSPEmployeePaid SSP ON AB.AbsenceID = SSP.AbsenceID                
    WHERE 
        ClientID = @ClientID
        AND SSP.ActualQualifyingDays>0                  
    ORDER BY 
        AB.ToDate DESC
END
```

But I cannot get it to function correctly...

Either I am getting an error because the IDENTITY function can only be used with a `SELECT...INTO` or if I miss that out it fails to load the right data...

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Well, you can use `Row_Number()` function instead of this - `IDENTITY( INT ) AS idCol` in your select statement something like this - `SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY AB.ToDate DESC) AS idCol, AB.FROMDate, AB.ToDate,....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, as the error said you can not use `IDENTITY( INT )` directly in the select statement. Alternatively you can use the [ROW_NUMBER()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186734.aspx) function in your select statement, something like this -

```
CREATE PROC sprc_EXPORT_SSP1_LoadtmpAbsencesTable   
    @ClientId int   
AS
BEGIN
    --DECLARE @ClientID int=9814
    ;WITH cteAbsencesTable
    AS
    (
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY AB.ToDate DESC) AS idCol, 
            @ClientID AS ClientID
            --, AB.AbsenceID
            , AB.FROMDate
            , AB.ToDate
            , AB.NoOfDays
            , AB.NoQualDaysForSSP
            , AB.AveWeeklyEarnings_Override
            , AB.AveWeeklyEarnings_Paid
            , SSP.QualifyingDaysInWeek
            , SSP.ActualQualifyingDays
            , CAST(CAST(SSP.ActualQualifyingDays AS DECIMAL(10,2))/CAST(SSP.QualifyingDaysInWeek AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS Weeks
            , SUM(CAST(CAST(SSP.ActualQualifyingDays AS DECIMAL(10,2))/CAST(SSP.QualifyingDaysInWeek AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS DECIMAL(10,2))) OVER(ORDER BY FROMDate ASC) AS TotalWeeksINTmpAbsence
            , (CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(AB2.ClientId) FROM t_Absence AS AB2 WITH (NOLOCK)  
                        LEFT JOIN t_AbsenceCategory AS ABR2 WITH (NOLOCK)  ON (AB2.AbsenceCategoryID = ABR2.AbsenceCategoryID)  AND DATEDIFF(DAY, AB2.ToDate, AB.FROMDate) - 1 >= 0 -- Precedes this absence
                        WHERE AB2.ClientId = @ClientID      
                        AND (DATEDIFF(DAY, AB2.ToDate, AB.FROMDate) - 1 <= 8 * 7) -- but not by more that 8 weeks           
                        AND ABR2.IsSSP > 0 AND ABR.IsSSP > 0
                        AND (DATEDIFF(DAY, AB2.FROMDate, AB2.ToDate) >= 3  
                            or ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, AB2.ToDate, AB.FROMDate)) - ISNULL(dbo.fn_GetTotalNonWorkingDays(@ClientID,AB2.ToDate, AB.FROMDate),0) = 1)
                        ) > 0 
                        AND dbo.fn_IsPIW(AB.AbsenceID, 4) = 1 -- this will take care of checking for continous days AND qualifying days
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Linked'
            , AB.DateCreated
            , SSPDays
            , (SELECT Descn FROM t_Locations WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE LocationId = dbo.fn_CheckClientHistory(@ClientID,14,AB.FROMDate)) AS 'Location' 
            , ISNULL((SELECT SUM(SSPPaid) FROM t_PayrollSSPEmployeePaid AS EP WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE EP.AbsenceID = AB.AbsenceID),0)  AS 'SSPPaid'         
        FROM 
            t_Absence AS AB WITH (NOLOCK) 
        LEFT JOIN 
            t_AbsenceCategory AS ABR WITH (NOLOCK) ON (AB.AbsenceCategoryID = ABR.AbsenceCategoryID)
        INNER JOIN 
            t_PayrollSSPEmployeePaid SSP ON AB.AbsenceID = SSP.AbsenceID                
        WHERE 
            ClientID = @ClientID
            AND SSP.ActualQualifyingDays>0                  
    )
    SELECT * FROM cteAbsencesTable
    ORDER BY idCol

END
```